# Nimbus Look & Feel ignoring ComponentOrientation in Russia

Tags: java, swing, orientation, nimbus

I have a diagramming tool with a lot of JOptionPane dialogs in it, and in Russia, one user (that I know of) is seeing the choice buttons in the order Cancel/No/Yes, i.e. RTL.  The user is running under Linux, and in this case the tool uses the Nimbus L & F.

Even after I force ComponentOrientation on all components to LTR in the code, and the user changes the locale from Russia to US, Nimbus still displays RTL.  So apparently Nimbus is using some different "locale" information from Java's.

I tried Nimbus on my machine (here in Canada), and it respects ComponentOrientation here when I set it to RTL - both using System L&F and Nimbus!  Very strange!

Can anyone shed light on this?  TIA

Comment: ignoring Russia! How racist! :) :P

Comment: @Paul Morrison everything depends of code that you distributed, AFAIK there isn't difference between Metal/System and Nimbus L&F for RTL/LTR, L&F haven't something with RootPane and setComponentOrientation

Comment: @mKorbel - didn't understand your comment - but I realize that I should have said that the code works fine *for him* when he uses my code modified to use System L&F.  Would appreciate it if you could expand on your explanation.